# custom header title getting overlaped by view

Tags: android, html, xml

Whenever I am trying to increase height of my custom Title bar it is getting overlapped by RelativeLayout below it.

I tried increasing height of header but it is getting overlapped.
Also tried decreasing height of relativeLayout that also didn't worked

Please find below my custom title and Relate layout.

Windows_title

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="#4A148C"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity_Main

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.jiq.sagar.javainterviewquestion.MainActivity">
    <!--<include layout="@layout/windows_title"
        android:id="@+id/include" />-->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:background="#00BCD4"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="#9f9b9b"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am setting Header using below code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Log.i(MY_TAG, "mainact");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.windows_title);
    setTitle("Interview Question");
    dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    getDatabase();
    mainlist();
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG9kb.png)

Comment: add a screen shit please what you really want

Comment: You meant screen shot ? ;):P

Answer (score 0):

```
You can fix this issue in two ways, first uncomment your include layout and choose one of the below answer...

1. use this line in your `ListView` component in `activity_main.xml` :--
       `android:layout_below="@+id/include"`

2. change your `activity_main` to `linearLayout` and put orientation to vertical, you can see in code below    


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/window_title" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:background="#00BCD4"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:divider="#9f9b9b"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi if I do this I am getting two headers
Added screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: i think you didnt change your default action bar from theme....please add .NoActionBar in parent of your res>styles

Comment: for example- <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">